# Adding Category Argument into an Array for WordPress Query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm new to customizing WordPress and am looking to query an array of posts within a certain category. I have a display that's showing an array of all posts from the site:

```
$arguments = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'showposts' => $postcount
        );
```

Basically, I want to be able to show an array of all posts that are only in the category "Nutrition". I figured it's a 'category' argument that would be added into this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `category_name` in your arguments.

```
$arguments = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'showposts' => $postcount
        'category_name' = 'Nutrition'
    );

query_post($arguments);
```

For more details read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Answer (score 2):

The argument is `category_name` not `category`

You can do this :

```
    $arguments = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'showposts' => $postcount,
        'category_name' => 'Nutrition'
    );
```